# Adobe CS5 upgrade

Tags: adobe-cs5, adobe-cs4

I purchased the Adobe CS5 Design Premium upgrade and was wondering if it will upgrade Adobe CS4 Web Premium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, software upgrade media will work as a fresh install.

If it's an install DVD, I'd be inclined to guess that it will indeed work. If it's a download, it's more up in the air.

Comment: I agree, I'm sure it will work as a clean install (which will be great) and usually it just asks for the previous version's key.  I just wanted to make sure that I could go from web premium to standard premium and didn't have to go from web to web or premium to premium.

Comment: Assuming it asks for the old key... Prolly not. If I recall correctly, Adobe has different key prefixes fr different editions of each software (Mac or PC). However, if they let you cross use the keys then it will work. I just don't know how their algorithm is designed.